# Angular: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when data retrieved from backend server with no updation of the View

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular2-changedetection

Please bear with me if you find this question pretty basic, as i am new to Angular and in frontend programming and javascript. I have three angular components A,B and C. The C's template is contained in B and B's template contained in A. A supplies user data to B via @Input params. Using the inputted info, component B makes a rest API call whose rest output is passed on to component C using C's @Input param. Component C is expected to display the data.

If i hardcode the display data in B's ngInit(), i have no qualms in displaying the data in Component C. HOwever, if i invoke the restAPI so as to supply server data, then i get the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. 
I have looked hi and lo and understand that this error is occuring in dev environment and has to do with change detection.

Besides this error, even though i do receive the api output, my display data does not change even though the rest output data has changed. I have tried using ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush(), changeDetectionRef.detectChanges() , etc but had no positive outcome.

Rest API returns a response which is extracted in the .then(). Below is the rest API call :

```
return this.http.request(url, options).toPromise()
        .then((response: any) => this.extractData(response))
        .catch((error: any) => this.handleError(error));
```

Would a blocking synchronous instead of async call to the rest API help?

Not sure what i need to do to mitigate this issue.Your kind help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a simple StackBlitz project to replicate this issue?

StackBlitz.com

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thanks for your response. As suggested by you, i created a sample project to reproduce the scenario in a similar fashion as dev environment. However, it worked on stackblitz. However, not working on my dev environment. Im using Typescript compiler @2.3.4.Would this be an issue here?

Comment: Any differences in the Angular versions? StackBlitz uses Angular 6 and even I have seen it work on Angular 6. But in Angular 5 or earlier we do get the expression changed after it has been checked error.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. For this reason itself i am moving from Angular 2 to Angular 6. However facing migration hurdles. Will respond once i get it working on Angular 6 or facing the same issue

Comment: Hi Siddharth, i have updated angular to 6.0 and the data showed up without any effort. However, the error shows up in dev mode which is fine for me. Looks like Angular 2.2 did not handle change management so well then. I somehow fail to understand how such a core functionality can be so broken and claimed incorrectly to be working by Google.

Answer (score 0):

After updating from Angular 2.2 to 6.0, the change synchronization functionality worked as expected. i.e, when the data arrives from the server, it is displayed in the UI. The error continues in dev mode.